# Initializing module variables in a UserForm

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I'm trying to use a variable that was initialized in a UserForm. But the simple example below just generates an empty MessageBox, regardless of what I write in the UserForm as the input.

```
Public X As String
Private Sub Module1()
  InputForm.Show
  MsgBox(X)
End Sub
```

InputForm:

```
Private Sub CommandButton_Done_Click()
  X = InputForm.ListBox1.Value
  Unload InputForm
End Sub
```

I'm new to VBA and I'm not sure how to debug the problem

Comment: That should work if you declare that `Public` variable on a `Standard Module` like `Module1`. Where have you exactly placed the first code?

Comment: You can't edit a userform entry from outside of the userform events, right? I think that's the point I was trying to make. The entry cannot be modified from the sub that calls the entry so I cant think of a piratical reason to call it (X) from there and not on a later sub, or is this logic faulty? @MathieuGuindon

Comment: @urdearboy the first problem is working off the `InputForm` class' default instance. The next problem is needing to deal with variables at a much wider scope than what's actually needed. Referring to the form's default instance inside that form's code-behind is also a problem. The form should be able to live on its own, and the code showing the form shouldn't need to care for what controls are on that form. See linked article of mine, above ;-)

Comment: @urdearboy re-reading your comment ...a form's controls are essentially public fields. When working off the default instance, you're essentially storing state in global scope - and you *can* absolutely tweak control values (heck, controls themselves!) from outside that form. The trick is to change the paradigm to a more object-oriented way, such that the calling code doesn't need to know or care about controls and their values.

Comment: I totally agree with Mathieu but for a beginner I would recommend to read [this](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-user-forms-1/) first and maybe also  an introduction to [classes](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-class-modules/) and after you "digested" that go to Mathieu's article. PS Just read the free part, no need to go for the pay part!

Answer (score 3):

You need specify that `X` is in the context of the module in which `X` exists. For example, if `X` exists as a module variable in module `Module1` you could change the `CommandButton_Done_Click()` subroutine to be

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton_Done_Click()
  Module1.X = InputForm.ListBox1.Value
  Unload InputForm
End Sub
```

It is important to note that you cannot declare the module which holds `X` as private if you want this to work.

Answer (score 2):

There are many problems waiting to bite you in the rear end down that road. [This article](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/) describes everything in details - here's the crux of it: flip the dependencies around, don't let the form run the show.

Create a new class module - that will be your *model*:

```
'class ExampleModel (class module)
Option Explicit

Private Type TModel
    Foo As String
    'other instance members
End Type

Private this as TModel

Public Property Get Foo() As String
    Foo = this.Foo
End Property

Public Property Let Foo(ByVal value As String)
    this.Foo = value
End Property

'other properties...
```

The members of this class will be everything the form needs to know. IOW that's where your `X` belongs.

The form is your *view* - it needs to know about the *model*, so you expose it to the outside world:

```
'class InputForm (UserForm module)
Option Explicit
Private m As ExampleModel ' at module-level, because you'll eventually want it to be WithEvents at one point

Public Property Get Model() As ExampleModel
    Set Model = m
End Property

Public Property Set Model(ByVal value As ExampleModel)
    Set m = value
End Property
```

All the form controls do, is manipulate the `Model` properties. So if you want to have `m.Foo = ListBox1.Value`, then you handle `ListBox1.Change` and do exactly that:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Change()
    m.Foo = ListBox1.Value
End Sub
```

Now all the "OK" button needs to do, is close the form:

```
Private Sub CommandButton_Done_Click()
    Me.Hide
End Sub
```

Notice it's **hiding** the form, not `Unload`ing anything. The form is an *object*, which means it was created by *something, somewhere* - and that something will not be expecting the object it created to spontaneously self-destruct. So you never `Unload Me`, and even more never (if that's a thing) do `Unload TheFormClassName`, because that would unload the form's *default instance*, and there's nothing anywhere that can guarantee that your form is always going to be shown off the default instance: it's a class like any other, it *wants* to be instantiated.

In order to avoid self-destructing the form, you need to handle the `QueryClose` event:

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = VbQueryClose.vbFormControlMenu Then
        Cancel = True
        Me.Hide
    End If
End Sub
```

Here, we cancel the closing/destruction of the form when the user clicks the red [X] button in the upper-right corner, and **hide** the *current instance* (the `Me` keyword always refers to the current instance of the class).

So what does the calling code look like now?

```
'module Module1 (standard module)
Option Explicit

Private Sub Test()
    Dim m As ExampleModel
    Set m = New ExampleModel
    Dim view As InputForm
    Set view = New InputForm
    Set view.Model = m
    view.Show
    MsgBox m.Foo
End Sub
```

Now if you want you can add logic in the `Model` property setter to pre-populate your form controls with values controlled by the calling procedure. Or you can have some `IsCancelled` property on the model, that's set when some `CancelButton` is clicked, and then the calling code can determine whether the form was cancelled, and conditionally show that `MsgBox`.

Global variables needed: 0.

Answer (score 1):

Your first sub opens the userform, thus your input box will be blank so you should expect a blank msgbox (Unless you have the box auto-populating).

A good practice (in my experience) is to work with your variables before Unloading the Userform, thus, you should handle them in your `CommandButton_Done_Click()`

1) Sub to Open Userform
2) Seperate Sub (Initialize) to control what happens when the userform is open (Control entry type, auto-populate fields, etc)
3) Final sub (Done_Click) to control what happens before the unload... (Validate input is string/int/etc, place inputs in cells, etc.)

```
Private Sub Module1()
  InputForm.Show
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton_Done_Click()
  Msgbox InputForm.ListBox1.Value
  Unload InputForm
End Sub
```

Comment: I've put up a quick answer, hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem. I found that context is different between "where is stored the main code" and "where is stored the form code"

so, I ended up in this way (I'll apply to your code) and IT WORKED BOTH DIRECTIONS

```
    Private Sub CommandButton_Done_Click()
      ThisWorkbook.X = InputForm.ListBox1.Value
      Unload InputForm
    End Sub
```